# Bind text box to value

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

How to bind to textbox and retrieve modified value on button click.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Sku objSku = new Sku();
            objSku.Name = "Test";
            Sku = objSku;
            frm.DataSource = Sku;
            frm.DataBind();
        }
        if (IsPostBack)
        {

            Sku = ViewState["Sku"] as Sku;
        }

    }

    public Sku Sku { get; set; }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Hers sku.Name should be equal to the value entered by the user . so that I can save the object.

    }

}
[Serializable]
public class Sku 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Html code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:FormView runat="server" ID="frm" >
    <ItemTemplate>


        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have direct access to your textbox as it's not in the FormView so:

```
String val= Textbox1.Text;
Textbox1.Text="what ever you are binding?"
```

I think you may need to be a little clear in your question as I don't understand what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're already binding to the field for displaying data.  Is this not working?  Within your button click event handler, you can retrieve the current value from `TextBox1.Text`.

Comment: But I want my sku object to be updated with textbox's value (it should notify the sku object automatically, without me having to do with setting the value to object explicity in button click. Is this possible. (Note I did not put the controls in form view , they are outside of it.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your view on postback you need to update the bindings.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Sku objSku = new Sku();
        objSku.Name = "Test";
        Sku = objSku;
    }
    if (IsPostBack)
    {

        Sku = ViewState["Sku"] as Sku;
    }
    frm.DataSource = Sku;
    frm.DataBind();

}
```